# VS 2015 cannot connect to GoDaddy Virtual Private Server

Tags: php, database, visual-studio, server, remote-access

I'm new so go easy on me! I have literally spent all day today trawling the internet to try and get a simple solution to this.

1. In VS 2015 community 'Server Explorer' I right-click 'Add Server'.
2. I have a GoDaddy VPS, in which I manually created a database.
3. In the Add Server dialog I enter my servers IP address 166.XX.XX.XXX.
4. I then click 'Connect using a different user name' and enter the server username and password.
5. I then click ok and get the following error:

***"Could not reconnect to "ip-166-XX-XX-XXX". Make sure the machine name and path are valid."***

This morning I had a normal hosting account. After talking to GoDaddy I subscribed to a dedicated VPS because I was told that would fix the issue. I then rang them again and they said everything is fine at their end and it must be a Visual Studio setting.

So I figure this is either:
1. A setting in my GoDaddy account. (I've been told its not that the settings are fine and they appear to be set to allow access)
2. A setting in VS. GoDaddy gave me a port number '3306' but I don't know if this is relevant or how to set it up in VS.

Please help!!!

Comment: why do you feel like adding a server for database. just set your connection strings and get going..

Comment: I want to add my existing database on the GoDaddy VPS as a data connection in my project and thought that adding the server was a good place to start.

Comment: no please do not add the server. I have a dedicated server on godaddy and I use connection string to connect and it works fine. If I do want to make changes to database I use SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Thank you but I cannot access my database as a data set and thought that setting up the server first was necessary.

Comment: In VS I go Project > Add New Data Source. Then 'Database' > 'Dataset'. I select 'New Connection' and 'Microsoft SQL Server'. I set the server name as '166.XX.XXX.XXX'. I have tried it with Windows authentication and SQL Server authentication. When SQL authentication is selected I used my server username and password. When I click Test Connection I get an error '...Network was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL server is configured to allow remote connections...' Any ideas? :-/

Comment: No I do not have any idea as to why you cannot add it as a data set. I just told you the proper way that I got myself to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Please Use a connection string in your web.config file with the IP and the credentials of your server. Your application would surely connect to your database. For remote management of your database use SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: So I decided to try connecting with MySQL instead and there is no problem. The MySQL Workbench connects fine and I can connect in VS using MySQL. Not sure why MSSQL wont work, I would prefer that since I have a variety of reference books on the language. Oh well...I'll use MySQL from now on. Thanks!